# How to fix "Chrome process did not produce websocket url within 2 seconds" when running chrome headless in Docker

Tags: ruby, cuprite

I'm using [Cuprite](https://github.com/gregoryduckworth/cuprite-base-ruby) driver for Capybara in my Ruby feature specs.

The specs run fine locally but fail with the error, `Chrome process did not produce websocket url within 2 seconds`, when the specs are run on our CI server. The CI server runs the specs within a Docker container.

The Docker image installs a recent version of Chrome, 77.0, from the Google PPA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The driver needs to be configured to pass the `--no-sandbox` option to Chrome:

```
Capybara.register_driver :cuprite do |app|
  browser_options = {}.tap do |opts|
    opts['no-sandbox'] = nil if ENV['CI']
  end

  Capybara::Cuprite::Driver.new(app, browser_options: browser_options)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just struggling with this issue on GitHub Actions. It turns out that the default `process_timeout` of 1 second is just too short, so Chrome didn't have time to start on the CI servers. It now works for me after extending `process_timeout` to a much larger value (20 seconds.) Here's the full code for my Capybara `:cuprite` driver:

```
  Capybara.register_driver(:cuprite) do |app|
    browser_options = {}
    browser_options['no-sandbox'] = nil if ENV['CI']
    headless = !ENV['SHOW_BROWSER']
    Capybara::Cuprite::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser_options: browser_options,
      headless: headless,
      process_timeout: 20
    )
  end
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :cuprite
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the problem was wrong permissions on the `/tmp/Crashpad` directory, which Chrome will create on first run.

Make sure the directory is writable by the current unix/linux user.

So e.g.:

```
sudo chmod -R go+rwX /tmp/Crashpad
```

to make the directory and all the contents writable by everyone.